# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=D:\Users\

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, odbc

i need help with the ODBC - JDBC Interface for CSV, with 32Bit Java 1.7.0_72

i recieved this code

```
    private void connectToCSV(String file) {
    try {
        debug.println(path + file +" "+this.file);
        if (this.file == null){
            this.file = file;

            gfdiConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={"+ driverCSV + "};DBQ=" + path );

        }
        if (this.file != file){

        this.file = file;
        gfdiConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={" + driverCSV + "};DBQ=" + path);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        debug.println("Error while trying to connect to CSV");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

but I didn't get run it.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=D:\Input\
```

I found a suggestion with

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
gfdiConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={"+ driverCSV + "};DBQ=" + path );
```

but this didn't work here.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

I checked also the Driver Name with

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

so whats the Problem with the Driver ?

Comment: Why you are using Type 1 driver. Type 1 drivers are not recommended and makes your java code non-portable. Oracle doesnt recomment using them and support for them is taken out in JDK 8. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html. If you need pur jdbc driver, please refer the third party drivers for CSV like http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: are you sure you runing with jdk 1.7 not jdk1.8?

Comment: Have your application display the value returned by `System.getProperty("java.version")`. What does it show you?

Comment: damn it, there is the jre 1.8.0_66 running.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.getProperty("java.version")` reported "1.8.0_66" so the application actually was running under Java 8, which has dropped the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC requires an activeX control to be installed that deals with providing a connection, meaning a program that directly interfaces with ODBC only needs to be sure that those drivers are installed on the system.  JDBC on the contrary requires that a library (jar file usually called a connector) is in the classpath that provides that connection.

What you're doing is trying to establish an ODBC connection *through* a JDBC connection, meaning presumably you need *both* the activeX control to be installed as well as the JDBC connector in classpath.  The name of the connector is correct, but it also must be in classpath.

What you need to do is to find the jar file providing the jdbc-odbc bridge and make sure it is in your classpath when your program starts.  You may have other problems, but at least if you don't see a ClassNotFoundException, you've fixed your missing jdbc driver issue.

You should eventually consider an alternative solution to using ODBC in Java.

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is included with Windows versions of Java 7, so there is no need to "find" a JAR or add it to the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @GordThompson Well then I suppose the problem is already resolved then, isn't it?  Oh wait, it isn't..

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have in java build path the respective JAR to prevent error in your project

Answer (score 0):

I added rt.jar manually to build path, now there is no more error with "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", but i got a NullpointerException

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at database.GfDIConnect.connectToCSV(CSVConnect.java:85)
at database.GfDIConnect.queryCSV(CSVConnect.java:147)
at database.GfDIConnect.gfdiBTRSTToPostgreSQL(CSVConnect.java:297)
at view.MainRefactor$58.run(MainRefactor.java:2434)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

CSVConnect.java:85 is

```
gfdiConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={"+ driverCSV + "};DBQ=" + path );
```

so was this solution to much quick and dirty ?

EDIT

I found the reason, there was still the build path libraries - JRE System Library on 1.8 JRE, after change to 1.7 it is working